# JavaScript closures - is there any alternative to manually reseting inner variables?

Tags: javascript, closures

JavaScript closures - is there any alternative to manually reseting inner variables?

Assuming we have the following closure:

```
var SearchItemModalModel = (function(){
    var filter1;
    var filter2;
    var filter3;
    [...]
    var filterN;

    var initVariables = function(){
        filter1 = undefined;
        filter2 = undefined;
        filter3 = undefined;
        [...]
        filterN = undefined;
    };

    return {
        Init: function(){
            initVariables();
        },

        SomeFunction1 : function(){

        },

        SomeFunction2 : function(){

        }
        [...]
    }
})();
```

The above is used to display a **modal with filterable list of items**. Every time user clicks **"Show available items"** - all filters should be set to **undefined**. User can display the modal as many times as he/she likes, **without reloading the page.**

Right now, I reset everything manually, by calling **initVariables()** inside the **Init function** - however every time there is a modification to the above JS "class", I have to manually add all new variables to the **initVariables()** function...

**So the question is:** is there any better way to do it - so that no manual reseting would be required? At first I thought something like this would work:

```
var searchItemModalModel = new SearchItemModalModel;
```

But now, after reading about JS closures, I don't think this is possible - or is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me like you are trying to re-implement objects.
Your example fits itself to the constructor pattern:

```
var SearchItemModal = function(){
    var filter1;
    var filter2;
    var filter3;
    [...]
    var filterN;

    var initVariables = function(){
        filter1 = undefined;
        filter2 = undefined;
        filter3 = undefined;
        [...]
        filterN = undefined;
    };

    this.Init: function(){
         initVariables();
    };

    this.SomeFunction1 : function(){

    };

    this.SomeFunction2 : function(){

    };
    [...]
};
```

Which you then use by creating new instances of it with `new`:

```
var searchItemModal = new SearchItemModal();
searchItemModal.Init();
```

I encourage you to read more about constructors and OOP in JavaScript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript), closures are great but there's a reason objects exist, and the way you wrote your code, the `filterN` variables will stay private either way.

Comment: I feel like a total idiot... I actually tried the approach You posted, but as it turned out, I tried to use it as a closure... without the "new" operator... I will test this more thoroughly tomorrow but it seems very promising... thanks :)

P.S.
In few tutorials, I read that closures ARE the preferred way to create JS "classes" and now I learn they are not... JS can be damn confusing

Comment: *>JS can be damn confusing*   It totally is, and is becoming more so with every addition to the language, as nice as they are. That's why if you really want to become good at JS I'd advise you to learn it by going through a proper book instead of cherry-picking random tutorials from the internet (e.g.: [eloquentJS](http://eloquentjavascript.net/), [JavaScript alonge](https://leanpub.com/javascript-allonge/read))

Comment: Thanks again - I actually was looking for a good JS book :) will gladly check out these two.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array instead of variables:

```
var N = 5;
var filter;

var initVariables = function(){
    filter = new Array(N);
};
// access variables by it's index (starting from 0)
// e.g.: filter[0]
```

EDIT: you can also hold all variables in one `state` object and initialize it with some default state like this:

```
var defaultState = {
    filter1: undefined,
    filter2: undefined,
    filter3: undefined,
    [...]
    filterN: undefined
};
var SearchItemModalModel = (function(){
    var state = defaultState;
    var initVariables = function(){
        state = defaultState;
    };

    [...]
    // access variable by object key
    // e.g.: state.filter1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - this is actually how I do it in some of the simple models, unfortunately, this becomes impractical in more complex views, where I have mix of multiple filter fields, some json data, some business logic data and so on (example that I posted, is from the "not complex" category). Most of the variables there, have more complex naming, and can't be easily looped over by index - I think lleaff answer is what I'm looking for - but I need to do more research.

Comment: Hmm I actually use "machina.js" state machine in my real JS closures - resetting all vars in some "InitState" might be a good idea - thanks. Shame though that this is still - error prone - manual labor :( but I guess this is simply how JS closures where design to work.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to set all variables of default state to undefined. You can simply have `defaultState = {}` and  if you try to access property, you will get undefined.